# Strange result of stripos function

Tags: php, string, stripos

I run this code:

```
var_dump(stripos($virtualhost[1], "cold="));
echo '----------------------<br>';
var_dump($virtualhost[1]);
```

And I get the following result:

```
bool(false)
----------------------<br>
string(206) "<virtual-mta vmta1-cold=\"\">
bla-bla-bla\"
```

As you can see, the first var_dump directly contradicts the second. What can this be connected with, and how to avoid or circumvent this?

UPD (closer to reality):

`<virtual-mta vmta1-cold="">
<domain *="">
  dkim-sign yes
  dkim-algorithm rsa-sha256
  max-msg-rate 1000000/d
  max-cold-virtual-mta-msg 1000000/d
</domain>
smtp-source-host there is a certain IP there is a certain domain
</virtual-mta>`

Comment: __Nope__ https://3v4l.org/jjIML

Comment: Is there something in the fact it says `string(206)`?

Comment: There are some Unicode characters that look similar, but aren't actually the same.

Comment: About similar characters: No, I copied a piece of output directly into the code, and that didn’t change anything.

Comment: About content of string(206):

<virtual-mta vmta1-cold="">
<domain *="">
  dkim-sign yes
  dkim-algorithm rsa-sha256
  max-msg-rate 1000000/d
  max-cold-virtual-mta-msg 1000000/d
</domain>
smtp-source-host there is a certain IP there is a certain domain
</virtual-mta>

Comment: Make an echo bin2hex($virtualhost[1]); and check if there is also contain 636f6c643d (for cold=).

Comment: It is very strange! bin2hex($virtualhost[1]) displays a hex in which there is no value 636f6c643d.

However, if you echo $virtualhost[1] itself, then copy the output, paste it into the code and process it with bin2hex, then the hex will contain this value.

But I need to process the value from $virtualhost[1]. How is the situation usually corrected in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are experiencing a similar problem.

In my case, perhaps the point was that I got my array from the contents of the file, which, in turn, was received from the ssh-stream. Here's what I did: I saved this file to local hosting and opened it in notepad. And I saw that the contents of the file are different from my output!

Where I have

`<virtual-mta vmta1-cold="">`

There was a local file

`<virtual-mta vmta1-cold>`

... and a few more differences.

My goal was to identify the paragraphs, where after vmta  comes this `'cold'`. Then I decided to start from the contents of the local file and instead of looking for the `cold=` fragment I started looking for the `-cold>` fragment. And it worked.

Comment: This is why you don't try to treat XML as text. You'd be better off putting it through an XML parser and then traversing the node tree.